# Vue.js fetching Laravel API JSON data

Tags: php, json, laravel, api, vue.js

I'm making a Laravel and Vue.js based app. On the main page I try to output projects categories with photos, it takes only category title and description, but I have a problem to fetch photos from API JSON:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "Bla",
            "description": "Bla Bla Bla",
            "project": [],
            "photo": [
                {
                    "id": 5,
                    "filename": "1.jpg",
                    "project_id": null,
                    "category_id": 1,
                    "created_at": "2019-09-19 12:52:16",
                    "updated_at": "2019-09-19 12:52:16"
                }
            ]
        },
        {},
        {}
    ]
}
```

My vue.js template is below, but output doesn't show photos based on filename at all, when inspecting on chrome dev tools it shows - src="/img/**undefined**". It looks like here is some mistake, but I can't find it.

```html
<template>
    <div>
    <div class="row" v-bind:pagenumber = "pagenumber">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" v-for="category in laravelData.data" :key="category.id">
            <a :href="'/category/' + category.id">
                <div class="projects-thumb" >
                    <img :src="/img/ + category.photo.filename" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                            <h3 class="pt-3">{{ category.title }}</h3>
                    <div class="projects-overlay">
                        <div class="projects-item">
                            <p class="mt-4 text-white">{{ category.description }}</p>
                        </div>  
                    </div>  
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>
<script>

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                category: {},
                photo: [],
                laravelData: {},
                id: '',
                succmsg:  true,
                showmodal: false,
                pagenumber: 1,
                actionmsg: '',
            }
        },
        methods: {
            categoryList(page) {
                if (typeof page === 'undefined') {
                    page = 1;
                }
                this.$http.get('/api/category').then((response) => {
                    this.laravelData = response.data.photo;
                    this.pagenumber = page;
                });
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.categoryList();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Could someone help me, because I can't find any solution on laravel and vue.js documentation pages.

Comment: try printing {{ category }} object in the template and check if the properties are ok

Answer (score 0):

Please replace this line

```
this.laravelData = response.data.photo;
```

By this line

```
this.laravelData = response.data[0].photo;
```

or

```
this.laravelData = response.data.data[0].photo;
```

and try.

Comment: Thanks, I did it. but without success. Got error: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined"

Comment: this.laravelData = response.data[0].photo; Got error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'photo' of undefined

Comment: this.laravelData = response.data.data[0].photo; Didn't show error, but it didn't output anything at all, I mean category.description and category.title

Answer (score 0):

I did some corrections by myself in vue template. 
Changed:

```
<img :src="/img/ + category.photo.filename" class="img-responsive" alt="">
```

to:

```
<img :src="/img/ + category.photo[0].filename" class="img-responsive" alt="">
```

and

```
 axios.get('/api/category').then((response) => {
                    this.laravelData = response.data.photo;
                    this.pagenumber = page;
                });
```

to:

```
 axios.get('/api/category').then((response) => {
                    this.laravelData = response.data;
                    this.pagenumber = page;
                });
```

So now template output correct image from database, based on JSON data, but it looks like that was only kind of workaround. 
Maybe someone could advise the best option based on good practice?