# VUE template problem to center text with text-center

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

I have problem to center h1 tag **category.title** with bootstrap property "text-center" in vue.js component, the **title** appears in left side. Everything else, for example **category.description** is centering correctly. It looks like only title refuses to be influenced by any align.

```
<template>
    <div class="row" v-for="category in laravelData">
        <h1 class="text-center">{{ category.title }}</h1>
        <p class="text-center pb-3">{{ category.description }}</p>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6" v-for="project in category.project">
            <div class="projects-thumb">
                    <img :src="/img/ + photo.filename" class="img-responsive" alt=""  v-for="photo in project.photo">
                    <h3 class="pt-3">{{ project.title }}</h3>
                    <p class="mt-2 p-3">{{ project.description }}</p>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                category: {},
                laravelData: {},
                id: '',
                succmsg:  true,
                showmodal: false,
                actionmsg: '',
            }
        },
        methods: {
            projectList() {
                var id = _.last( window.location.pathname.split( '/' ) ); 
                axios.get('/api/category/'+ id).then((response) => {
                    this.laravelData = response.data;
                });
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.projectList();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Maybe the problem is because of several loops in this template?

Comment: Inspect the element in the developer tools to see what CSS is being applied. It could be that something else is setting the alignment, or it could be that the element is only as wide as the text. It doesn't explain the alignment problem but I'm surprised you aren't receiving error messages about multiple root nodes.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. It was influenced by the class="row". Now it works.

Comment: @skirtle what do you mean about multiple root nodes. Here is zero errors. But sure, maybe it is some kind of workaround with these 3 loops in row. Maybe you able to advise? All data comes from RESTfull API JSON, so I'm trying to fetch data from multidimensional array of category,>project>photo. Here is an array in this post - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58028663/vue-js-fetching-laravel-api-json-data).

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#A-Single-Root-Element While your template may appear to have a single root element the `v-for` on the `<div class="row">` could cause it to output multiple nodes unless `laravelData` only contains a single entry. If it does only contain a single entry then using a `v-for` is not really appropriate.